# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE)

Tags: php, syntax

I've read through all the different answers online here but none of them seem to be working for me,

Heres my code:

```
<?php 
 $connect= mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("absence");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM absence WHERE first_name = 'megan' ");
         WHILE
    ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query));

        $first_name = $rows['first_name'];
        $last_name = $rows['last_name'];

        echo "$first_name $last_name";      
    endwhile;
    ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php ?

Answer (score 1):

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):
```

that semi colon should be a colon.

Also, switch to pdo or mysqli. mysql_ is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for this should be

```
while (CONDITION):
    //
endwhile;
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

But you should not use the alternative syntax in this case.

Also `mysql_` methods are deprecated
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$connect= mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db.tbl WHERE first_name='megan'") or die(mysql_error());

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

  $first_name = $rows['first_name'];
  $last_name = $rows['last_name'];

  echo "$first_name $last_name";  
}
```